# Raspberry Pi: Voltage Converters and IO-Pins

Tags: level-shifting, raspberry-pi

I want to drive an LCD that needs 6V-power from a RaspberryPi. The Pi has a 3.3V logic power-pin, and a 5V power-pin that's directly connected to the MicroUSB-PowerSupply.

- Am i right in the assumption that all MicroUSB-Supplies are regulated, so the PI expects / delivers regulated 5V-voltage on this pin?
- What happens if connect a voltage-converter (Step-Up?) to this 5V line and connect this circuit to the GPIO-InputPins? Is that even possible? Does the circuit then have 5V or the voltage that the converters delivers?

Comment: Connecting 6V to the GPIO is likely to overheat and damage your device. You need a "level shifter", which depending on frequency could be as simple as one transistor per line in "open collector" configuration.

Comment: 6 V for power, I assume? Not for I/O, right?

Comment: Correct. 6V for Power.

Comment: Why is 'Arduino' in the title for this question?

Comment: @Vorac please don't make absurdly trivial single-character edits to truly ancient, problematic questions.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has been abandoned with critical detail missing for **eight years**.

Answer (score 3):

As pointed out before, build a 6V power supply and connect transistors (possible FETs) to the GPIO pins to drive the display. If you have trouble, check:

- [is it safe to drive a MOSFET from an output pin of a microcontroller?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/13075/9640)
- [Microcontroller Interfacing –  Part 9: FET Transistor Switching](http://www.w9xt.com/page_microdesign_pt9_fet_switching.html)
- [When is a MOSFET more appropriate as a switch than a BJT?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/13079/9640)
- [Basic Transistor Drivers for Micro-Controllers](http://www.bristolwatch.com/ele/transistor_drivers.htm)