# How to disconnect a component with a microcontroller output?

Tags: switches, low-power

I have a circuit that uses a PIC microcontroller and an [OpenLog from Sparkfun](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/9530) (a microSD card logging module ).  Everything is running at 3.3V.

In order to conserve power when it is not in use, I want to be able to use a signal from the a PIC output pin to completely disconnect the OpenLog from power and ground when it is not in use.  Can someone provide some suggestions?

I have tried using a 2N7000 between the OpenLog and ground, but I think that the voltage drop across it is not allowing the OpenLog to get a high enough voltage to turn on.

The reason that I want to disconnect it completely is that there seems to be leakage current via the Rx and/or Tx pins if either the power or ground remain connected.

Do I need a solid state switch or something?  I would rather keep things inexpensive.  I am a bit of a novice and this seems like it should be simple, but I need help!

Comment: Do read the datasheet - it has warnings about lost data when power is removed, so make sure you're cognizant of all the requirements.

Comment: Here is an idea: use an "
8-Bit Buffer/Line Driver With 3-State Outputs" to power the module. Those have a chip enable pin. I don't know how adequate that is, just giving an idea.

Answer (score 5):

Changing the common voltage [GND in this case], can cause errors in interfaces.  We can put in a MOSFET to switch the power supply of the chip in this case, instead of switching the ground.

Use a P-type MOSFET to connect between the 3.3V rail and the 3.3V input of the Open Log.  An example is the [BS250](http://w3.id.tue.nl/fileadmin/id/objects/E-Atelier/doc/Datasheets/Transistoren/BS250.pdf).  The Gate of the P-type MOSFET should have a 100K pull up resistor to 3.3V, so that the voltage of the rail "stops" the MOSFET from turning on.  Source should be connected to 3.3V, Drain is connected to the Open Log.  If you want to turn the OpenLog "ON", have the uController pin that is connected to the Gate of the MOSFET be pulled LOW.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to a specific component for my conditions.  I think that with this high side component and the input pin suggestions below, I should be able to get rid of most of the wasted current.

Answer (score 2):

You're on the right track, and I think just a tweak will get you there.

The 2N7000 has R<sub>DS(on)</sub> specified only for gate voltages of 4.5 V or higher. Since you're only able to drive the gate with 3.3 V, there's no telling what the performance will be. This is probably why you are seeing excess voltage drop across it in the "on" state.

See [this recent question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/49846/what-is-a-popular-cheap-and-robust-substitute-for-2n7000-mosfet-for-use-with-3-3) for some suggestions of alternative FETs to use in 3.3 V systems.

> The reason that I want to disconnect it completely is that there seems to be leakage current via the Rx and/or Tx pins if either the power or ground remain connected.

Whatever i/o pins of your microcontroller are connected to the other module, it would be a good idea to put them in tristate when you disable the module. Even better, put them in tristate and have a weak pull-up or pull-down (e.g 10 - 50 kOhms) to keep them from floating.

Comment: On the PIC, does "put them in tristate" mean to set them as an input?  My understanding is that they are high impedence as inputs and would not draw much current then?

Comment: It could be the same as setting as input --- I don't know about PICs specifically. Maybe a PIC expert will chime in?